# Jquery/Ajax $(var).serialize() Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Hell everyone.

I'm working on an ASP.NET Web API project and I get an error here:

```
    function LoadGraph(text) {
    console.log(typeof(text));
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/Graph/LoadGraph",
    type: "POST",
    //contentType: "application/javascript",
    data: $(text).serialize(),
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
})
}
```

The text is a string and the error is

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <and here there is the value of the text varibale>
```

And it happens at the line `data: $(text).serialize(),`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you shoud serialize an input element not its value

Comment: What is the value of `text`?

Comment: @ArunPJ the text come from an uploaded file, do you want to say that I should serialize the <input...>?

Comment: @Shaunak It's too long to post it here but it come from a uploaded file which could be very big (from 1 to 100 Mo) and it has some special characters like " ' & and �

Comment: are you trying to sent the content of text as a request parameter

Comment: Yes it is what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to post the text stored in variable `text`, you just put

```
...
data: text,
...
```

`$(text)` means you want jQuery to lookup an element or expression specified by `text` which is completely not what you want.

Comment: It seems to work, thank you very much, I didn't yet completely understand this.

Comment: First of all, you have to realize what you need to "serialize". You don't actually need to "serialize" anything if you are just sending the value of `text` verbatim to the server. Second, why do you need to call `$(...)` if you already have the text as a string? You only need to do so if you are holding a reference to the <input> element and in that case you call `$(input).val()`.